# How to encode transaction instruction data from an Anchor program?

Tags: transactions, javascript, instructions, transaction-instructions

I'm trying to encode the transaction instruction data from Anchor using the documentation (https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/javascript-api#interacting-with-custom-programs) but this is not working. What am I doing wrong and how should I change the code to get the expected transaction instruction?

```
const amount1 = new BN(1000000);
const amount2 = new BN(2000000);

const params = { amount1: amount1, amount2: amount2 };

const allocateStruct = {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
  // @ts-ignore
  layout: struct([u32('instruction'), u32('amount1'), u32('amount2')]),
};

const data = Buffer.alloc(allocateStruct.layout.span);
const layoutFields = Object.assign({ instruction: 0 }, params);
allocateStruct.layout.encode(layoutFields, data);

const keys = [
  {
    pubkey: new PublicKey('public_key_1'),
    isSigner: false,
    isWritable: true,
  },
  {
    pubkey: new PublicKey('public_key_2'),
    isSigner: true,
    isWritable: true,
  },
];

const instruction = new TransactionInstruction({
  programId,
  keys,
  data,
});
```

Comment: I think it's not anchor code, it's rather solana native program. Are you trying to make native program call? Then please describe what the error is, and plz show your program rust files.

Comment: Yes, I was using anchor code. I've decided to use a complete different way to resolve the issue instead, thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP solved their own problem. If you believe that the solution to this problem would be of general interest to people with the same problem, please update the question (if necessary), answer your own question, and accept your self-answer.